# Meteor Acessing Data from modal

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm building a marketplace where people can post listings of things they would like to sell and others can respond to these listings. I have implemented modals to allow users to view the listings that they have responded to in detail (users can fill out a form that sends an offer for a certain item, this information is saved in Mongo). I'm having some trouble accessing data from Mongo and displaying it on the modal.

As far as showing each offer, that is working properly and my code for that is:

```
<template name="profileManagerOffers">
    <div class="profileCard oneDiv">
        <ul class="profileCardUl">
            {{#each offer}}
                {{> ManagerCardOffer}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{> ModalSentOffer}}
</template>
```

I'm relying on a helper function for this being set which looks like this:

```
    offer: function() {
        var id = Meteor.userId();
        return Offer.find({
            creator_id: id
        });
    },
```

This works fine and each offer is displayed with some information regarding it.

When the user clicks one of these offers, A modal is supposed to open  with information corresponding to the offer. I'm having some issue with getting this data. With the #each block I can correctly print out ALL the information but how do I refine it to the specific correct offer when clicked.

Here is a photo

[image: photo]

Again, as you can see each offer is displayed but when the "View Offer" button is clicked the modal is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking button save details in session variable

**NOTE:** I suppose 'view offer' button is in `ManagerCardOffer` template

```
Template.ManagerCardOffer.events({
 'click #viewOffer': function(){
    Session.set('selectedOffer', this)
  }
})
```

then in the modal

```
<template name="ModalSentOffer">
  {{#with selectedOffer}}
    // code to dispaly offer
  {{/with}}
</template>

Template.ModalSentOffer.helpers({
  selectedOffer: function(){
   return Session.get('selectedOffer'):
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, view offer is on the ManagerCardOffer template I didn't include. I had considered using Sessions vars but thought this was the wrong thing to do. Thanks. Do you know if it is ok practice to use Session vars like this in similar situations?

Comment: you can use reactive var `http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg`,it is  better to use them, try declaring a reactive var in `profileManagerOffers` and try to access it from child templates, I'm not sure it works or not